# POST 406 (Not Acceptable) ERROR when returning List<String> from backend

Tags: java, angular, spring, request, response

I have angular-java web app. I am trying to pass xlsx file to the backend, and to parse some information. The backend gets the request, and it process it fine. But then I return the List of strings from server to front I get the 'POST 406 (Not Acceptable) ERROR'.

This is my method in **service.ts** on front:

`public importFile(file: File, planId: number, fileName: string): Observable<String[]> {`
`const formData: FormData = new FormData();`
`formData.append('file', file, file.name);`
`const headers = new HttpHeaders();`
`headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');`

`return this.http.post<String[]>(this.getUrl() + '/importFile/' + planId + '/' + fileName, formData, {headers: headers, responseType: 'json'});`
`}`

And this is my method in **controller**:

`@PostMapping(value = "/importFile/{partijaId}/{fileName}") @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK) public List<String> importFile(@PathVariable(value = "partijaId") Long partijaId, @PathVariable(value =    "fileName") String fileName, MultipartFile file) throws IOException, EdocFieldsException { return service.importStavkiOkvirnogSporazuma(partijaId, file, fileName); }`

Anny suggestions?

Comment: not sure why you setting that header with 'Accept', 'application/json'.  This tells the server what you can accept as a response.  It then sees that the controller is trying to respond with a List<String> and throws the 406.  (just don't send the headers...)  I think your responseType is wrong too.  (You're sending formData which will automatically set the type to multipart form/text...)